# Random size and position of button: unexpected behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-constraintlayout

**My `ConstraintLayout`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**My simplified code:**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Random rand = new Random();

    private Button btn;
    private float widthPixels, heightPixels;
    private float minBtnSize, maxBtnSize;


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Obtaining screen's display properties. */
        final DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        widthPixels = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        heightPixels = displaymetrics.heightPixels; // includes BotNavBar
        heightPixels -= 162; // size of the "Virtual Nav Bar" at the bottom
        float minDim = Math.min(widthPixels, heightPixels);
        minBtnSize = minDim/25;
        maxBtnSize = minDim/2;


        /* Setting up the experiment's Button*/
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){

                /* Touch Events. */
                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                            
                        /* Move and resize the button. */
                        launchNewAttempt(x, y);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        /* Setting up the beginning Button's state. */
        init();
    }


    /**
     * Initializing the Button shown at the very beginning.
     */
    private void init() {
        btn.setX(0);
        btn.setY(0);
        btn.setWidth((int)widthPixels);
        btn.setHeight((int)heightPixels);
    }


    /**
     * Called whenever the user releases the experiment's button (pressed "UP").
     */
    private void launchNewAttempt() {

        /* Random size for the "new" button. */
        int size=(int)(minBtnSize+(maxBtnSize-minBtnSize)*rand.nextDouble());
        btn.setWidth(size);
        btn.setHeight(size);

        /* Random position for the "new" button. */
        float dx = rand.nextFloat() * (widthPixels - size);
        float dy = rand.nextFloat() * (heightPixels - size);
        btn.setX(dx);
        btn.setY(dy);
    }
}
```

**Expected behavior:**

A button that fills the whole screen appears at the beginning. Once pressed, that same button is resized (as a square, with sides at least 1/25 th and at most 1/2 of the width of the screen) and moved around the screen at random positions. Every time the user presses that button again, it behaves the same way (new random position and size).

**My problem:**

`btn.setX()` and `btn.setY()` don't seem to behave as expected. I would have thought that they would determine the absolute position of the button within the screen, but using the following sample-code for `init()` has a weird behavior:

```
btn.setX(0);
btn.setY(0);
btn.setWidth(150);
btn.setHeight(150);
```

The size seems to be okay, but the position seems to be relative to the middle of the screen (though it also seems to depend on the size of the button since using the code presented earlier it properly fills the whole screen). I would want such position to be relative to the top-left of the screen (excluding the top's ActionBar/TitleBar, and also excluding the bottom's NavigationBar).

When running my current code, the `Button` actually some times ends up being off screen. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code replacing the root node of the layout by a `LinearLayout` and it was working properly, so this means the problem is related to the inner logic of `ContraintLayout`. Knowing that I tried to change the position of the button thinking about constraints instead of absolute position, particularly regarding the top and start margins of the button. Therefore the `launchNewAttempt()` method can be something similar to this:

```
private void launchNewAttempt() {
    final int size = (int) (minBtnSize + (maxBtnSize - minBtnSize) * rand.nextDouble());
    final int left = (int) (rand.nextFloat() * (widthPixels - size));
    final int top = (int) (rand.nextFloat() * (heightPixels - size));
    final ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) btn.getLayoutParams();

    layoutParams.width = size;
    layoutParams.height = size;
    layoutParams.leftMargin = left;
    layoutParams.topMargin = top;

    btn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

I also kept only two contraints to place the button in the layout and removed the end and bottom ones:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:text="Start"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: I was working out a solution as you were typing: I'm writing it out. Had I known that simply swapping for a `LinearLayout` everything would have worked, I would have done that. Thanks for your input anyways: I'm sure other people will benefit from it.

Comment: I tried out your solution and it's nicer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, would you mind explaining why removing `the end and bottom` constraints was necessary?

Comment: It might not be mandatory to remove these constraints, but they are completely unnecessary if the button is placed only depending on the top and start ones. So I removed them to be sure to avoid any side effect due to these additional constraints.

Answer (score 0):

**Wang**'s answer is correct (and more concise/elegant), but since I actually figured it out just a few minutes before he posted, I will also post my solution.

As global variables:

```
private ConstraintSet cSet = new ConstraintSet();
private ConstraintLayout cLay;
private float density;
```

In the `onCreate` method to initialize the variables properly.

```
/* To be able to manipulate the position and size of the Button. */
cLay = findViewById(R.id.main);
cSet.clone(cLay);
density = displaymetrics.density;
```

The adapted `launchNewAttempt` method:

```
private void launchNewAttempt(int x, int y) {

    /* Random size for the new button. */
    int size = (int)(minBtnSize+(maxBtnSize-minBtnSize)*rand.nextDouble());
    cSet.constrainWidth(btn.getId(), size);
    cSet.constrainHeight(btn.getId(), size);

    /* Random position for the new button. */
    float dx = rand.nextFloat() * (widthPixels  - size) / density;
    float dy = rand.nextFloat() * (heightPixels - size) / density;
    /* Possible negatives because position relative to center of screen. */
    final float middle = .5f;
    if(rand.nextFloat() < middle)
        dx = -dx;
    if(rand.nextFloat() < middle)
        dy = -dy;
    cSet.setTranslation(btn.getId(), dx, dy);

    /* Applying the changes. */
    cSet.applyTo(cLay);
}
```

Nonetheless, I would advise using **Wang**'s answer.